# Run an ant task in maven build phase before war is packaged?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-war-plugin, maven-antrun-plugin

When deploying a webapp I need to update some variables in UI resources, unzip some assets and concat some files, currently this is achieved via an ant task. I'm trying to run this task in the maven build process using something like this...

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>deploy-ui</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <property name="buildDir" value="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}" />
                    <ant antfile="build.xml" target="static-assets" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The above fails because the files have not yet been copied into target directory. If I set the phase to "package" the ant task runs fine and all the files are created/amended, but it's no help as the .war has already been built before the ant target is run.

Basically, I need to run my ant target near the end of the prepare-package phase.

Having looked though the [Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) I can't workout how to expose the more granular Goals to the antrun plugin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you thought about doing those ant tasks by using "pure" maven plugins instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since I did not get any answer on my comment I guess that you want to stay using `maven-antrun-plugin`.

From what I've learned and experienced, if two plugins are to be executed on the same phase, then they will be executed in the order they are declared in `pom.xml`.

For this to work you will have to add the `maven-war-plugin` in the `<plugins/>` list after the `maven-antrun-plugin`.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>deploy-ui</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <property name="buildDir" value="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}" />
                    <ant antfile="build.xml" target="static-assets" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- First step is to disable the default-war build step. -->
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <!-- Second step is to create an exploded war. Done in prepare-package -->
            <id>war-exploded</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exploded</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <!-- Last step is to make sure that the war is built in the package phase -->
            <id>custom-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

Added some more executions so that the `default-war` is first disabled, then the war is exploded and lastly the war is packaged.

Comment: this was a very helpful answer for my problem. However, I had a little different setup: exploded(prepare-package) --> copy-resources(prepare-package) --> war(package). In order to not overwrite what the war:explode task generated, I had to point `<warSourceDirectory>` to an empty directory for war:war execution.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed this is a place where the lifecycle doesn't provide the granularity needed.  I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144507/944849) for someone earlier.  It's not an exact answer to your question but the technique may apply.