# spring boot package does not exist error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jar

I'm compiling my project with `mvn clean package`, and failed with `package does not exist`.

The detail command:

- Get the jar file `target/xxxx.jar` by running `mvn clean package` in source project.
- install this jar file by running `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/xxxx.jar  -DgroupId=com.company -DartifactId=source-package-name  -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar`
- add code to target project, which will use some functions in source project
- compile target project by running `mvn clean package`, and it just failed with `package does not exist`

here is the source project `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>source-package-name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>source-package-name</name>
    <description>xxxx</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xmx6144m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

here is the target project pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-package-name</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>target-package-name</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <smartv-common.version>0.3.5s</smartv-common.version>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- Exclude those since they are copied from the profile folder for 
                        the build -->
                    <exclude>system.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <finalName>xxxxx</finalName>
        <!-- Set a compiler level -->

        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>

                    <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html 
                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729513/how-to-overwrite-files-in-the-war-file-during-maven-build -->
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- Resources from the activated profile folder -->
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes/</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>system.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>

                </configuration>

            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Add dependency to your target project.

Comment: @talex i did add dep， but it still does not work

Comment: So I'm think weather the way of package is right

Comment: You can check it by looking in local maven repo (usually ia=n `~/.m2` folder). Find your module folder and check its `pom.file`. Then check that you dependency is correct.

Comment: it is here, but still failed

Comment: Add that `pom.xml` to you question and update target `pom.xml` with dependency you added.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ideally, you shouldn't use a Spring Boot application (something that's been repackaged) as a dependency. From [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar):

> Like a war file, a Spring Boot application is not intended to be used as a dependency. If your application contains classes that you want to share with other projects, the recommended approach is to move that code into a separate module. The separate module can then be depended upon by your application and other projects.

If the proposed solution isn't possible in your situation, the documentation goes on to describe an alternative:

> If you cannot rearrange your code as recommended above, Spring Boot’s Maven and Gradle plugins must be configured to produce a separate artifact that is suitable for use as a dependency. The executable archive cannot be used as a dependency as the executable jar format packages application classes in BOOT-INF/classes. This means that they cannot be found when the executable jar is used as a dependency.
>
> To produce the two artifacts, one that can be used as a dependency and one that is executable, a classifier must be specified. This classifier is applied to the name of the executable archive, leaving the default archive for use as dependency.
>
> To configure a classifier of exec in Maven, the following configuration can be used:
>
> ```
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <configuration>
>                 <classifier>exec</classifier>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
> ```

Comment: one more question, I just find all `@Autowired` in my source target is null, is there something wrong?  @andy-wilkinson

Comment: This explanation took me out to the light. Thank you

Comment: That explanation is crystal clear and works for me! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I was facing this issue and solved it by adding this code in Common-service.pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Isn't it exactly the same as in the other answer? Looks like it to me.