# Fail by import dependency from local m2 repository

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have created 2 dummy projects by [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/) (Maven, Java):

1. `com.example.lion`
2. `com.example.zoo`

I want to import `lion` project to `zoo` project as dependency.

So I go to `lion` folder and execute:

```
mvn clean install

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=target/lion-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom -DpomFile=pom.xml
```

Then I add dependency to `zoo` `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>lion</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

After that I execute `mvn clean install` in `zoo` folder.

I never got errors in console.

So now if I go to any class in `zoo` project, and import:

```
import com.example.lion.*;
```

Then `mvn clean install`, I get error:

> **package com.example.lion does not exist**

In my IntelliJ IDEA I can see, that `lion` dependency is in *External Libraries* and *maven-tool*, but why I can not access that from code?

Comment: Does the maven project `com.example.lion` actually have a java package in `com.example.lion`? By this i mean does your `src` directory for the lion project have the children `main/java/com/example/lion`?

Comment: Additionally the maven install line reads like you are putting a pom-file into the repo and not the jar file.

Comment: Because if that directory doesn't exist then there would not be a package called `com.example.lion` to import in the zoo project.

Comment: You don't have to and _should not_ perform `mvn install:install-file ...` explicitely in addition to `mvn install`! The `install` phase (invoked with the former executed) has the [Install Plugin's `install` goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html) bound to it by default which does this automatically for you, by using the project's POM declarations of the [Maven Coordinates](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) `<groupId>`, `<artifactId>`, `<version>` (GAV).

Comment: cheemcheem: yes it exists. start.spring.io create all structure automatically
DrHopfen: what would be correct install line?
Gerold Broser: i tried only with `mvn install` now, but the problem is not solved

Comment: @NikolajSobolev Yes, this was just a hint for proper usage of Maven and such unrelated to your error. Sorry for not mentioning, but due to the 600 characters limit in comments...

Comment: @Gerold Broser you are looking like maven expert. pls help me guy :D, try the same, what I did in header. just create 2 projects on start.spring.io and add one to other as dependency. me noob has something forgot

Comment: @NikolajSobolev I tried it in Eclipse 2019-03. `import com.example.lion.*;` and `new LionApplication();` in `ZooApplication.main()` works there.

Comment: @Gerold Broser can you please push your code to github, and sent me all mvn commands that u have used. thx man!

Comment: @NikolajSobolev I did nothing else but what you describe: 1) Create the two projects on https://start.spring.io/. 2) Import them into Eclipse. 3) `lion $ mvn install` 4) add the dependency and the two lines of code to `zoo`. 5) `zoo $ mvn install`. Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099592/1744774) already?

Comment: @NikolajSobolev I can reproduce your issue on the command line. I'm not an expert for spring boot but if you look inside the lion.jar the structure seems odd to me. The com.example.lion package is not located directly in the jar but under: `.m2\repository\com\example\lion\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\lion-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\BOOT-INF\classes\com\example\lion\` probably this is normal for a spring boot application, but if this is supposed to be some kind of lib maybe it should not be a spring boot application by itself.

Comment: found solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45479060/spring-boot-package-does-not-exist-error