# Can I defer, in Maven, the resources filtering after the execution of a plugin?

Tags: maven, resources, filtering, pom.xml, wro4j

I'm using *wro4j* for *js* and *css* aggregation. So, I work with my *js* files and in maven build time, *wro4j* executes and creates the unique *js* files I need.

There is one *js* file that has a couple of variables based on the profile from *pom.xml* (related to the environment, such as url to find something).

When I build the application, I can see inside the *war* file the replaced variables in the *js* file.
But, when the plugin for *wro4j* make the aggregated *js* file, takes the files from *webapps/js* and not from *target* folder (which it is right), so, the aggregated *js* file has the expression variables instead of the replaced ones.

I want to **defer the filtering execution to run after the *wro4j* plugin**. It is possible?

These are the variables on the *js* file (called *global.js*):

```js
var mvnProfileEnvName = "${environment.name}";
var mvnProfileFullSearchUrl = "${full.search.url}";
```

And I have the following code in *pom.xml*

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
      <environment.name>dev</environment.name>
      <full.search.url>url/for/dev</full.search.url>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>test</id>
    <properties>
      <environment.name>test</environment.name>
      <full.search.url>url/for/test<full.search.url>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <properties>
      <environment.name>prod</environment.name>
      <full.search.url>url/for/prod</full.search.url>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/js</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <includes>
        <include>global.js</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/wro</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>

  </plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <minimize>true</minimize>
        <jsDestinationFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/wro/js/</jsDestinationFolder>
        <cssDestinationFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/wro/css/</cssDestinationFolder>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
<build>
```

Comment: Possibly related to [this stackoverflow question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10144507/944849).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting `<filtering>false</filtering>` and then manually configure an execution of `maven-resources-plugin` to occur at a later phase, with filtering enabled.  Place this after your wro4j plugin declaration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>filter-resources</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals><goal>resources</goal></goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html