# maven - filtering files under src/main/webapp/jsp while building the war

Tags: jsp, maven, filtering, maven-war-plugin

In my java webapp project I have all the jsp files placed at **`src/main/webapp/jsp.`**
How do I enable the filtering and replace property placeholders with actual values while building the war?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <filters><filter>${basedir}/src/main/resources/filter.properties</filter></filters>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/jsp</directory>
                <targetPath>/jsp/</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Attaching the console output of mvn package command :

```
[exec] [INFO] Copying webapp webResources [projectbasedir/src/main/webapp/jsp] to [projectbasedir/target/myapp]
[exec] [INFO] Copying webapp resources [projectbasedir/src/main/webapp]
```

The jsp files are getting filtered properly in `"Copying webapp webResources"` step but `"Copying webapp resources"` step overwrites all these changes since it copies everything from `src/main/webapp folder` to target folder afresh.

How do I make this filtering work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Files got overwritten in maven project when building a war](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133485/files-got-overwritten-in-maven-project-when-building-a-war)

Comment: Can you post the resource configuration you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace it with this config, the difference is to use `directory` as `src/main/webapp` and include subfolder in `includes`.
For whatever reasons when `directory` matches with `warSourceDirectory` it works fine.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <filters><filter>${basedir}/src/main/resources/filter.properties</filter></filters>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <targetPath>/jsp/</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>jsp/**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```